# How do I get a Belkin n52te keyboard working?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have this [N52TE](http://www.belkin.com/n52te/index1.html) keyboard from when I used it on my Windows, it works out of box fine but it only acts as the left side of a normal keyboard, is there a way to edit custom buttons on Linux? There is no official driver for Linux.

Answer (score 4):

The author of [Keyboarding Master](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/) generously added support for the N52TE after I asked about it recently. It is supported in a [developer preview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/files/Developer%20Preview/kbmaster.20130829.tar.bz2/download), and I can confirm it works!

I'm unsure whether the developer preview can be installed alone, without previous drivers being installed to root. I have an official release installed to /opt, and then ran the preview from a folder in /home. At any rate, I suspect a full release with N52TE support will happen and resolve this uncertainty.

If you are running Ubuntu with Unity, there's a chance the 'taskbar' icon for the program may not appear. I would suggest keeping the main window open, and not hidden, so you don't lose your interface to disable and configure the drivers. If this happens, though, you'll have to kill the process from the terminal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Correct, the install is necessary for the developer preview to work since it requires UDEV modification which the installer handles.  I am fixing a few bugs and will be releasing a new version very soon that has the n52te support.

Comment: 0.1.5 Release is now out: https://sourceforge.net/p/kbmaster/blog/2013/08/release-015-352/

Comment: I downloaded and installed 0.1.5 with n52te support and when I run it (terminal) I get **/opt/kbmaster-0.1.5/run.bash line 9: lib/java-linux-x64/bin/jave: No such file or directory** I do not have that directory. I am a 64bit user, I have OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime installed should I link that editing the file or do I need a specific other java installed?

Comment: Can you download the 64-bit version? 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/files/Beta/kbmaster-0.1.5-linux-x64-installer.run/download

Comment: That version does work "Better" I am able to start it with the .jar file but it makes my pc work at like 1frame/30s. Before it would crash my system just after the local network screen. now I was able to get past that. get the add device. but by this it was running my pc slow. extremely slow.